# Dynamically add Filter Expression to the Gridview to Filter Two Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please see the following code:

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = "";
        foreach (ListItem l in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (l.Selected)
            {
                HD1.Value += l.Value + ",";
                if (SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression == "")
                    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression += " TSOType like '" + l.Value + "%'";
                else
                {
                    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression += "or TSOType like '" + l.Value + "%'";
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I am dynamically assign filter expression to the Gridview when the items in checkbox is checked. This will give me the expected result when Cloumn "TSOType" meet the requirements. What I want now is to add one more column filter to the FilterExpression. For example, now I have

```
SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression += " TSOType like '" + l.Value + "%'";
```

But I want make it to

```
SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression += " TSOType like '" + l.Value + "%' + TSOStatus like '" + j.Value + "%'";
```

How should I code this, do I need another for loop?

Comment: Where is the value for `j` coming from?

Comment: @DennisR it is from another checkboxlist if I created.

Answer (score 0):

> The `SqlDataSource` control supports filtering data only when in the
>   `DataSet` mode.

Refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) for details. So add `DataSourceMode="DataSet"` for the `SqlDataSource` object.

And you can use `AND` operator to add multiple conditions for the `FilterExpression`

```
SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression += " TSOType like '" + l.Value + "%' + AND TSOStatus like '" + j.Value + "%'";
```